# Generate menu in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm attempting to get the Generate menu to pop up in Android Studio by using ctrl + n or ctrl + alt and it's not working. Is there an alternative way to get this to come up? I need the Generate menu in order to get to the Constructor option next. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the Jetbrain Cheat sheet

try `Alt + Insert`

for additional key-map this is the link :

[JetBrain Cheat Sheet](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: I'll save this for future reference but it didn't bring up the menu that I need. Thanks anyway.